# Why do we have condensation and temperature drop around prefab fireplace?

Tags: insulation, fireplace, condensation

We moved to a house with a wood burning prefab (or zero clearance) fireplace that was installed when the house was built (1986). It is in a corner in our living room, diagonal to an exterior wall and an interior wall (see picture... It's hard to explain).

My question is about insulation, temperature and condensation. We noticed that the exterior wall (to the left in the picture) is at a significantly higher temperature than the thin sections of wall on both sides of the actual fireplace box.

Why is the fireplace wall much colder? Is it because of the cold air in the flue? Is there likely to be any insulation on the wall behind the fireplace like in any other exterior wall in the house? We discovered condensation in the upper corner of the fireplace wall that meets the exterior wall (at the ceiling level) and so we are wondering about all that system. Also, the damper is broken, and it could be letting some cold air in. Could that be the reason for the temperature of the wall and the condensation?

Thank you so much for any insight!

[image: fireplace and condensation location]

Comment: Is this an ongoing problem or is this a new issue that you've noticed because your local outdoor temps have dropped to significantly below normal?

Comment: Recent. Last year, there was no condensation and it was not this cold either.

Comment: A broken damper could certainly contribute. I have quite a bit of experience with this type of setup, having built a few, demolished a few and owned one, but I won't be able to answer most of your questions from my chair. It'll take some investigation on your part.

Comment: If you don't mind making a few tiny holes in the wall, try driving in a small finish nail every 3/4 to 1 inch across the width of the narrow walls beside the fireplace to test for presence of wall studs (just barely above the base board may minimize visibility of the holes). Do you find lots of wood in the walls, or open spaces? An electronic stud finder may or may not be useful for this, since some need to be calibrated on a section of wall where there are no studs. Wood conducts more heat than insulation does.

Comment: I will try doing that. If I can't figure it out, I will try to get a hold of a professional. Thank you!